# How can I process incoming email messages with PHP?

Tags: php, email

I want to process incoming emails to an address and insert them into a mysql database. I am using a grid-service media temple host with SHH access but I have no idea where to start. I also want to store attachments or copy them to a directory on my host and save the url in the database.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get email and their attachments from PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114953/how-to-get-email-and-their-attachments-from-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to process incoming mail in PHP is [imap_open()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php), which you can use to open a mailbox, either using IMAP4 or POP3.
You would need to run your script periodically, or at least regularly run [imap_ping()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-ping.php) to 'poll' for new messages.

Answer (score 1):

Why not pipe the emails instead of using `imap_open()`? This would allow you to access the email immediately as it comes in, and then decide if you even want it stored in the inbox.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you don't know where to start, my one suggestion would be to look at the inbound email service offered at [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/). I believe there are several such services.