# Email received with attachment and attachment automatically uploaded to FTP

Tags: php, email, ftp

How would I go about the following:

- Client send email with attachment to upload@mycompany.com
- Email server detects email received
- Attachment uploaded to remove FTP location
- Email sent to client confirming upload

Would like to use PHP.

Comment: What email server are you using? Pretty much all unix-based ones can have an account pipe incoming mail to a program which could do your extraction/ftping.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114953/how-to-get-email-and-their-attachments-from-php

Answer (score 0):

If @Marc B answer is not possible, you can use the php_imap extension. Some examples are available [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch17_04.htm), and of course at php.net

AFter that, uploading via FTP is trivial using PHP FTP functions ([here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php))

Comment: php_imap would depend on a php script reaching out to the mail server to check if there's any mail. I think OP wants something that happens automatically the instant an email with attachment comes in

Comment: That's why I've added the first "if" :) I know that in my company, I can't access the email server directly (it's provided by Gmail)